# serial communication reset /etc/profile (linux)

Tags: c, linux, serialization

I am working on a serial communication between a pc (ubuntu) and an embedded linux (2.6.24) board. The serial communication by itself seems to work (i use Serialib from http://serialib.free.fr/html/index.html ) but everytime my application on the board stop to listen the /etc/profile file is called by the board (this thing don't happen for application not using the serial).

It is to know that while i launch the application on the board, i have a gtkterm opened on the PC to follow the terminal of the board (which use the serial port too), i would think that this is the culprit of this reset of /etc/profile but i am not sure.

My code for the reading application

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "serialib.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QProcess>
#include <iostream>

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined( _WIN64)
#define         DEVICE_PORT             "COM1"                               // COM1 for windows
#endif

#ifdef __linux__
#define         DEVICE_PORT             "/dev/ttyS0"                         // ttyS0 for linux
#endif

int main()
{
    serialib LS;                                                            // Object of the serialib class
int Ret,res;                                                                // Used for return values
char Buffer[128];

// Open serial port

Ret=LS.Open(DEVICE_PORT,115200);                                        // Open serial link at 115200 bauds
if (Ret!=1) {                                                           // If an error occured...
    printf ("Error while opening port. Permission problem ?\n");        // ... display a message ...
    return Ret;                                                         // ... quit the application
}
printf ("Serial port opened successfully !\n");

// Read a string from the serial device
Ret=LS.ReadString(Buffer,'\n',128,5000);                                // Read a maximum of 128 characters with a timeout of 5 seconds
                                                                        // The final character of the string must be a line feed ('\n')
if (Ret>0)                                                              // If a string has been read from, print the string
    printf ("String read from serial port : %s",Buffer);  
else
    printf ("TimeOut reached. No data received !\n");                   // If not, print a message.

// Close the connection with the device

LS.Close();

return 0;
}
```

I send "TEXT\n" to the serial while in the limits of the timeout and i have "String read from serial port : TEXT" appearing on the terminal copy in gtkterm followed by "running etc/profile". Like i said before i suspect the fact that i am using the serial with gtkterm at the same time i send the string but i must have it working to use the board and i would like your opinion on this issue.

Thank you for the future answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your system configured to run another program (`login` or its kin) on the same serial port.

Check `/inittab`.  Make sure no instances of `login` or `getty` are being launched with that port.  (You will still want it running on the other serial port, the one you use for your terminal session)

Comment: I don't seems to have a program running on that port, my inittab look like this : ::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
::respawn:-/bin/sh

tty2::askfirst:-/bin/sh
tty3::askfirst:-/bin/sh
tty4::askfirst:-/bin/sh

::restart:/sbin/init

::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a

Comment: @Wowy: Is that on your Ubuntu development box or the target system?

Comment: @Wowy: If you put a sleep before calling `LS.Close()`, when the extra line concerning `/etc/profile` appear?  I suspect it is triggered by closing the port.

Comment: When putting a sleep right before calling LS.Close() (for example sleep(5)) the line concerning /etc/profile appears after the sleep (here the 5 seconds). I tried deleting the LS.Close() line but even then /etc/profile is still called after reading. If i don't run the application on the target but still send a string on the serial i can see the serial "TEST" that i send appearing on the terminal (like a command which i would enter manually) of the target and /etc/profile is not called. But this don't give me the possibility to work with the string on the target.

Comment: @Wowy: wait, do you have one serial port for terminal and a second one for string data?  Or you are trying to do both with a single port?

Comment: Right now it is on the same serial port.

Comment: Ah well then you can't disable the shell on that port, since that's what gives you the terminal. The effect you're seeing is because closing the port changes the control pins, possibly CD or RTS.  If you can avoid that, your terminal resets should stop.

Comment: I tried not using the terminal and simply send the command as strings on the serial. The reset still happen. So i should try to see how i am closing (To be honest this reset is not a problem for later in my work, but i was mainly curious about why it happened because i often have terminals opened)